# Java library for cleaning up user-entered title to make it show up in a URL?

Tags: java, url, text

I am doing a web application. I would like to have a SEO-friendly link such as the following:

```
http://somesite.org/user-entered-title
```

The above user-entered-title is extracted from user-created records that have a field called title.

I am wondering whether there is any Java library for cleaning up such user-entered text (remove spaces, for example) before displaying it in a URL.

My target text is something such as "stackoverflow-is-great" after cleanup from user-entered "stackoverflow is great".

I am able to write code to replace spaces in a string with dashes, but not sure what are other rules/ideas/best practices out there for making text part of a url.

Please note that user-entered-title may be in different languages, not just English.

Thanks for any input and pointers!

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is some kind of "**SLUGifying**" the prhase into a URL, so it is SEO-friendly.

Once I had that problem, I came to use a solution provided in [maddemcode.com](http://maddemcode.com/java/seo-friendly-urls-using-slugify-in-java/). Below you'll find its adapted code.

The trick is to properly use the `Normalize` JDK class with some little additional cleanup. The usage is simple:

```
// casingchange-aeiouaeiou-takesexcess-spaces
System.out.println(slugify("CaSiNgChAnGe áéíóúâêîôû   takesexcess    spaces  "));
// these-are-good-special-characters-sic
System.out.println(slugify("These are good Special Characters šíč"));
// some-exceptions-123-aeiou
System.out.println(slugify(" some exceptions ¥123  ã~e~iõ~u!@#$%¨&*() "));
// gonna-accomplish-yadda
System.out.println(slugify("gonna accomplish, yadda, 완수하다, 소양양)이 있는 "));
```

Function code:

```
public static String slugify(String input) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
            .replaceAll("[^ \\w]", "").trim()
            .replaceAll("\\s+", "-").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

In the source page (http://maddemcode.com/java/seo-friendly-urls-using-slugify-in-java/) you can take a look at where this comes from. The small snippet above, though, works the same.

As you can see, there are some exceptional chars that aren't converted. To my knowledge, everyone that translates them, uses some kind of map, like Djago's urlify ([see example map here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8391#comment:18)). You need them, I believe your best bet is making one.

Comment: acdcjunior, thanks so much for sharing your experience and code!

Comment: acdcjunior, your slugify method removes those Korean characters in your example. Aren't those characters allowed in URL?

Comment: They aren't. In an ordinary URL, they will be converted to URL encoding. For instance, the chars `완수하다`, in a slugifying method, you can either: **(1)** remove them; **(2)** convert them to their url encoding representation `%EC%99%84%EC%88%98%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4` (although this is not much Human readable/SEO friendly, I'm afraid); or **(3)** create a list where you will map each one of those chars to an ascii one (`a-z`) and then the method will change them. This last option is not standard and may not make sense. `¥` may make sense to be an `y`, but does `円` make sense as well?

Comment: Thanks so much for your analysis, which apparently shows that you have walked this path, very far!

Comment: I tried your method and the original one you mentioned. It appears that your method produces cleaner results (on that string with Korean characters). Nice!

Comment: I tried some other suggestions I got over the internet, and this last one I posted seem to work the best. This is easy to customize, though. If you want to customize and need help, don't hesitate in coming back. And, since we are in the topic, check out this question, it's a quick read and maybe it's interesting for your current development: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064124/url-styling-why-should-i-use-idsslug-names-products-id-product-name-o

Comment: you are reading my mind! I was thinking about th /products/[product-id]/[product-name] approach overnight and your past post exactly confirms that. In this /products/[product-id]/[product-name] approach, the product-name part is purely for search engines, correct?

Comment: Mappings such Djago's urlify are just for translating other languages into English, correct? If so, how about people speaking other languages? If we do some similar mapping for people speaking each other language, then the mapping would be too big a task. Ok, let's just consider translating other languages into English, wouldn't be better to use Google Translate as a service for this type of translation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to URL-encode a string. It's possible in core Java, without using external libraries. [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) is the class you need.

Languages other than English shouldn't be a problem as the class allows you to specify the character encoding, which takes care of special characters like accents, etc.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for chiming in. I want the text in the url is more readable. Using URLEncoder would turn space character " " into a plus sign "+", which would make text harder to read.

Comment: @curious1 if you simply want to get rid of the `+` sign, replace it after URL-encoding your string (or better, replace the spaces before encoding). The reason I suggested the class is because it gets rid of all illegal characters that might end up in your URL. Nothing stops you from customizing it further. Just like in @acdjunior's answer.