# Java convert string in URL compliant version

Tags: java, url

I need a function that can convert my string like 
"How, how to change my password?" into
"how-how-to-change-my-password"

I will use this string as a part of URL that I will use in my browser
I tried URLDecoder.decode(string,"UTF-8")
but no luck. Can I use some function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String q = "How, how to change my password?";
    q = q.replace(" ", "-").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z-]", "");
    String url = URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

It replaces all  with `-` and the removes all punctuations (except `-`). And in case something is missing `URLEncoder` makes sure it's a valid url.

You may want to check out the lib recommended here: [Java library for cleaning up user-entered title to make it show up in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679088/java-library-for-cleaning-up-user-entered-title-to-make-it-show-up-in-a-url)

Comment: It seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to check out the lib recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679088/java-library-for-cleaning-up-user-entered-title-to-make-it-show-up-in-a-url

Comment: Yes, it's even better. Thanks!!

Comment: If this solves your issue, please accept the answer and close the question